# Best appraoch to build a Parent/Child lists inside SharePoint and manage the relation inside Power Apps

Tags: sharepoint-online, lookup-column, powerapp, powerapps-forms, parent-child

I have 2 SharePoint online lists:-

1. Customer
2. Project.

Where each project will be assigned to one and only one customer, here is the Project create/edit form:-

[image]

So i am not sure how i can build the relation inside SharePoint + allow the user to select a Customer when creating/editing  project?

I were planning to create a SharePoint lookup field inside the Project list which reference the Customer lists, but since we will have more than 5,000 customers, so the lookup will not work inside Power Apps.. so can anyone advice on these 2 points please:-

1. how i can build the relation inside SharePoint, for example using lookup will have the limitation of not working if we have more than 5,000 customers
2. allow the user to select a Customer when creating/editing  project inside the above Power App form?

Thanks

Comment: We had a similar problem and ended up using https://plumsail.com/cross-site-lookup 
Works like a charm... Our lookup field had 20k records.

Comment: @Aslan sorry using 3rd part tools is not an option for us

Comment: I understand... This tool is using jslink to achieve this functionality. It will not be an easy thing to do but it is possible using csom to get lookup values...